# I want to use img sprites but I;m not sure it's possible

Tags: css

I'd like to use image sprites for performance but how would I do it in this situation?

I have a tile layout that uses divs with anchor tags and right now I have a class for each image that positions it in a certain place on the tile anchor tag. Each tile is not going to have the same positioning for it's image.

If I used a sprite how would I position the image uniquely in the tile? BY setting the x y coordinates i would just be setting where the image is on the sprite, not where it should be in the div, right?

Example HTML:

```
<div class="tileFlip"> 
    <a class="size4 red i-projects">
        <h1>Project Portfolio</h1>
    </a>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.i-projects {
    background-image: url('../../../img/icons/projects.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 49% 80%;
}
```

Comment: The background-position refers to where you want the top left corner of the background to appear in relation to the current element.  Using a precise unit (em, px, pt, rem, etc) is a lot more common for sprites.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, all you need to do is declare the difference in position.

```
.i-projects {
    background-image: url('../../../img/icons/projects.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display:block;
    background-position: 49% 80%;
}

.i-projects .green{
    background-position: 69% 40%;
}
```

Positions are usually expressed in pixels for this type of application, and they refer to the position of the background sprite.

Comment: This just ends up showing several sprites instead of the one I want to display. The problem is that the anchor tag that I want to display a sprite on as a background image is much larger than the actual sprite itself.

Comment: Adjust the size and position of the CSS declaration. I have no idea how your sprites are laid-out on the image.

Answer (score 0):

If the tiles are going to be changing dynamically you would have to use Javascript to dynamically adjust the CSS.  For instance, using jQuery you could do:

```
$(oneOfThoseDivs).css({
    backgroundImage: 'url("../../../img/icons/projects.png")',
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundPosition: "49% 80%"
});
```